# MySqlException: Timeout expired - Increasing Connection Timeout Has Had No Effect

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-timeout

I have a query that is taking longer to execute as the database increases in size. The query is optimized and necessary, but my C# Console Application has recently been giving me this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Timeout expired.
```

Increasing the connection time out in the connection string doesn't help; I increased it from

> Connect Timeout=28800

to

> Connect Timeout=128800

but I'm still getting the error despite this change.

If I run the query from MySQL workbench it only take about 10 seconds, so I'm not sure how to prevent this Unhandled Exception.

Are there other things, besides "the time a query takes", that can produce this exception?

Comment: Change the CommandTimeout  not the ConnectionTimeout.

Comment: The [`CommandTimeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-commandtimeout) **not** the [`ConnectionTimeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-connectiontimeout).

Comment: public static string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.2;user=user1;database=database1;port=3306;password=testPW;Pooling=true;Connect Timeout=28800;Command Timeout=28800";

I'm still testing.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I haven't experience the timeout since I set the Command Timeout, as shown in my connection string above.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've had this problem before.  ConnectTimeout property only applies to time outs that occur when connecting to the database, not for queries.

**CommandTimeout** however specifies how long it should wait for the query to return. I believe the default is 30 seconds. Double check the documentation for your MySql library, but for SqlCommand the CommandTimeout is in Seconds not milliseconds.

Comment: In MySQL is also seconds. also - 0 is no timeout.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try adding "default command timeout=360" in your connection string; eg

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;default command timeout=20;
```

This option is available from Connector/NET version 5.1.4.

[I lifted this from [connectionstrings.com/mysql/](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Answer (score 3):

If you can show us your method, we can help find the bugs.

If history (and SO ) has taught me anything, its

```
"You better be using Paramaterized SQL statements before posting any code"
```

If you are unsure on how to use parameterized commands here is an example ( taken from one of the answers where I didn't use parameterized SQL )

```
var command = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM tblPerson WHERE LastName = @Name AND Height > @Height AND BirthDate < @BirthDate", connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", lastname);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", height);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", birthDate);
```

Try that if you haven't already and post some code :)